# Is our robots.txt file formatted correctly?

Tags: robots.txt

I'm trying to make sure our robots.txt file is correct and would greatly appreciate some info. We want all bots to be able to crawl and index the homepage and the 'sample triallines' but that's it. Here's the file:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /$
Allow: /sample-triallines$
Disallow: /
```

Can anyone please let me know if this is correct?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: specify your index page path in `Allow: /$` field otherwise Allow and Disallow on last line are same

Comment: If you want to support *all* bots, note that `Allow` (and characters with special meaning, like `$`) are not part of the robots.txt spec, so not all bots support these.

Answer (score 0):

You can test your XML sitemap directly with a [robots testing tool](https://technicalseo.com/seo-tools/robots-txt/) or within the webmaster tools of most major search engines (e.g. [Google Search Console](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6062598?hl=en)). Your current robots.txt file will work for most crawlers for the exact URLs you mentioned (e.g. https://www.example/ and https://www.example/sample-triallines).

However, just to note, if your URLs deviate from these exact URLs they will be blocked to crawlers (e.g. tracking parameters). For example, the below URLs will be blocked with the current robots.txt setup, which may or may not be acceptable for what you're working on.

- https://www.example/index.html
- https://www.example/?marketing=promo
- https://www.example/sample-triallines/
- https://www.example/sample-triallines?marketing=promo

  If any of these above URLs need to be crawled you'll just need to add additional directives into the robots.txt file as needed and test them within the robots testing tools. Additional information on robots directives can be found [here](https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt).

Hope this helps